# How to include QTD and YTD in Redshift query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am working on SQL script in Redshift. As per the requirements, I have to show the month but the amounts need to be calculated QTD and YTD. How to ignore month dimension from the calculation and how to have YTD calculation for each month?

Example:

- Month February: I need to show sum of amount for Jan and Feb as QTD and YTD
- Month June: I need to show sum of amount April, May and June in QTD and Jan-June in YTD
- ETC.

In selection, I need to show month, year with other dimension.